# Array gets emptied when i try to add new stuff to it (PHP)

Tags: php

I am trying to add stuff into an array after every click a user makes on a category but for some reason it keeps replacing everything in the array. I can't figure out where I am going wrong. I've tried 'googling' it and every example i find looks similar to what i have written. Please Help!

these functions are store in core.php

```
function getStoreBacktrace($cat) {
    include("config.php");
    $backtrace = array();
    if ($cat != 0) {
        array_push($backtrace, $cat);
    }
    if (count($backtrace != 0)) {
        foreach($backtrace as $c){
            echo getBackCatName($c);
        }    
    }
    print_r($backtrace); // Put this to see what output is
}

function getBackCatName($c) {
    include("config.php");
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM `home_store_cats` WHERE `id`="'.$c.'"';
    $r_query = mysql_query($query);
    $result = mysql_fetch_array($r_query);
    echo ' > <a href="?cat='.$result['id'].'">'.$result['name'].'</a>';
}
```

this function prints out a list of links the user can click on

```
function getStoreCat($cat) {
    include("config.php");
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM `home_store_cats` WHERE `main`="'.$cat.'" ORDER BY `name` ASC';
    $r_query = mysql_query($query);
    echo '<ul>';
    while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($r_query)) {
        echo '<li>';
        echo '<a href="?cat='.$result['id'].'">'.$result['name'].'</a>';
        echo '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

and it gets called in store.php

```
<?php
include("config.php");
include("core.php");
$backtrace = array();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title><?php echo getSiteTitle().' :: '.getSiteSlogan(); ?></title>
</head>
<body>
    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <!-- Backtrace -->
                <a href="store.php">Home</a>
                <?php echo getStoreBacktrace($cat, $backtrace); ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <!-- Categories -->
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo getStoreCat($cat); ?></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td>
                <!-- Products -->
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <?php echo getStoreProducts($cat); ?>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

now everytime a user clicks on a link that is made from the function `getStoreCat($cat)` it refreshes the page with new links to click on and new products to show depending on what `$cat` they chose. i want to push the `$cat` to the `$backtrace` array.

Comment: Where exactly are you calling `getStoreBacktrace()`? The function initializes and populates a _local_ array variable `$backtrace` on each call, so if you call it more than once, it isn't going to retain previous values.

Comment: PHP "mysql_" **"extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used."**

Comment: Also `count($backtrace != 0)` should be `count($backtrace) != 0`

Comment: Thanks for showing where it gets called. I don't see how it could get called multiple times in order to build up the `$backtrace` array?

Comment: @rackemup420 plz see edits to my answer, based on the info you added to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right here:

```
$backtrace = array();
```

You are effectively resetting the array for each call to `getStoreBacktrace()`.

**EDIT:**

Thanks for fixing your question. Now it's clear that the issue is you need to make `$backtrace` persistent through multiple page views. Do this using sessions:

*Page template*

```
<?php
session_start(); // enable sessions
include("config.php");
include("core.php");
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
etc...
```

*Function definition*

```
<?php
function getStoreBacktrace($cat) {
    include_once("config.php"); // use include_once() to prevent possible errors
    if (!isset($_SESSION['backtrace']))
        $_SESSION['backtrace']= array();
    if ($cat != 0) {
        array_push($_SESSION['backtrace'], $cat);
    }
    ...
```

Comment: should i store $backtrace somewhere else?

Comment: @rackemup420 I just added a possible solution

Comment: i just changed it to this and it still erased everything in the array.

Comment: @rackemup420 did you remove this line from `getStoreBacktrace()`: `$backtrace = array();` ?

Comment: @rackemup420 can you edit your question and show where/how you call `getStoreBacktrace()`?

Comment: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$_SESSION' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp1\htdocs\homelife\core.php on line 191` line 191 = `$_SESSION['backtrace'] = array();`

Comment: @rackemup420 Oops, missing a closing paren `)` on that line. Updated my answer.

Comment: now is there a way to check if what im pushing to the array already exists?

Answer (score 1):

Everytime you call getStoreBacktrace you instantiate a brand new array in $backtrace.